# Unable to remove the foreign languages unicode codes

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a .csvfile with multiple foreign languages(russian, japanese, arabic,etc) info within. For example, a column entry look like this:<U+03BA><U+03BF><U+03C5>.I want to remove rows which have this kind of info.
I tried various solutions for, all of them with no result:

```
test_fb5 <- read_csv('test_fb_data.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

or applied for a column:

```
gsub("[<].*[>]", "")` or `sub("^\\s*<U\\+\\w+>\\s*", "")
```

or

```
gsub("\\s*<U\\+\\w+>$", "")
```

It seems that R 4.1.0 doesn't find the respective chars. I cannot find a way to attach a small chunk of file here.
Here is the capture of the file:

```
                        address
33085                                           9848a 33 avenue nw t6n 1c6 edmonton ab canada alberta
33086                                 1075 avenue laframboise j2s 4w7 sainthyacinthe qc canada quebec
33087 <U+03BA><U+03BF><U+03C5><U+03BD><U+03BF><U+03C5>p<U+03B9>tsa 18050 spétses greece attica region
33088                                       390 progress ave unit 2 m1p 2z6 toronto on canada ontario
                                                     name
33085                                md legals canada inc
33086                             les aspirateurs jpg inc
33087 p<U+03AC>t<U+03C1>a<U+03BB><U+03B7><U+03C2>patralis
33088                    wrench it up plumbing mechanical
                                                               category
33085 general practice attorneys divorce  family law attorneys notaries
33086                                                              <NA>
33087               mediterranean restaurants fish  seafood restaurants
33088            plumbing services damage restoration  mold remediation
             phone
33085  17808512828
33086  14507781003
33087 302298072134
33088  14168005050
```

the 3308's are the rows of the dataset
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: @ktiu, I do not know how to use dput(). I typed in console with myfile, 6 rows in. Nothing happens.....

Comment: `dput(head(test_fb5))`

Comment: @ktiu I typed in console dput(head(test_fb5) and print the respective rows in console. How to add the rows to my question.....

Comment: Edit the question and paste from your console into a code block

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative character class to remove the `<U...>` codes:

```
gsub("<[^>]+>", "", x)
```

This matches any substring that:

- starts with `<`,
- is followed one or more times by any character **except** the `>` character, and
- ends on `>`

If you have other substrings between `<`and `>`, which you do not want to remove, just add `U` to more specifically target unicode codes, thus: `<U[^>]+>`

Data:

```
x <- "address 33085 9848a 33 avenue nw t6n 1c6 edmonton ab canada alberta 33086 1075 avenue laframboise j2s 4w7 sainthyacinthe qc canada quebec 33087 <U+03BA><U+03BF><U+03C5><U+03BD><U+03BF><U+03C5>p<U+03B9>tsa 18050 spétses greece attica region 33088 390 progress ave unit 2 m1p 2z6 toronto on canada ontario name 33085 md legals canada inc 33086 les aspirateurs jpg inc 33087 p<U+03AC>t<U+03C1>a<U+03BB><U+03B7><U+03C2>patralis 33088  wrench it up plumbing mechanical category 33085 general practice attorneys divorce  family law attorneys notaries 33086                                                              <NA> 33087               mediterranean restaurants fish  seafood restaurants 33088            plumbing services damage restoration  mold remediation phone 33085  17808512828 33086  14507781003 33087 302298072134 33088  14168005050"
```

Comment: @ Chris Ruehlemann   Thank you Chris! It ssems it is working on a single column, but when I print the dataframe on console, the entries are the same.  I typed that: test_fb5$name <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", test_fb5$name). When I print the test_fb5, the entries still show the unicodes. What I did wrong?

Comment: Print the test_fb5$name:
[1] "md legals canada inc"            
[2] "les aspirateurs jpg inc"         
[3] "πάτραληςpatralis"                
[4] "wrench it up plumbing mechanical" When I print the test_fb5, the"name"entries looks unchanged:                md legals canada inc
2                             les aspirateurs jpg inc
3 p<U+03AC>t<U+03C1>a<U+03BB><U+03B7><U+03C2>patralis
4                    wrench it up plumbing mechanical   Why is that? It seems that my changes are lost....

Comment: Sorry, as long as you do not provide a reproducible data set you cannot expect anybody to be able to help you efficiently. So, make the dataframe, or a part of it, available in **reproducible** format.